# How to set a variable by using another variable to name

Tags: javascript

I am making a console style website and im making a command to read and set a variable. The user would type into an input box "Var (Variable) (True/False)". I have separated each section by spaces using an array so "Var Red True" would be "Var", "Red", "True".

I need help with using the (Variable) part of the array as a variable name. So if a user puts in "Var red true", I need a way to tell JavaScript to set the Variable "red" to true, without using a bunch of ifs statements if possible.

This is my code so far.

(Following Code is inside of an if statement that checks if the commandinput (the input box text) starts with "VAR" after pressing enter onto the text box.) (The "delivery(4)" function called isn't responsible for setting the variable, it is used to print text to a log.)

```
    var variablearray = commandinput.split(/(\s+)/).filter( function(e) { return e.trim().length > 0; } );
    console.log(variablearray); // ["VAR", "(VARIABLE)", "TRUE/FALSE/READ"] 
    //Read the inputted variable - What variable will change
    var input_var = variablearray[1];
    //Read the 3rd term - The action to be preformed (True/False/Read) - What to do to variable
    var third_term = variable array[2];
    if (third_term == "TRUE") {
        //**I need help with this part**
        delivery(4, "Variable '" + input_var.toString() + "' has been set to " + window[input_var.toString()] + ".")
    } else if (third_term == "FALSE") {
        delivery(4, "Variable '" + input_var.toString() + "' has been set to " + window[input_var.toString()] + ".")
    }
```

I have tried to use without any avail.

> VAR input_var.toString = True  - and -   VAR input_var.toString() = True

"input_var.toString()" does return the variable that needs to change, however I can't find a way to change said variable.
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks to rajjix the issue has been solved! Using "window[user_input_var] == true", to change the variable works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript variable depend on the lexical scope they are declared/defined in, wether it be a global scope or inside some function, if you're just defining your variable inside a the script tags, you might as well say

```
window[user_input_var] == true
```

which is equivalent to (in case user input was "red")

```
var red = true.
```

The most important part you should get out of this is variables in javascript are lexically scoped somewhere. Lexically scoped means physically declared somewhere, and based on that declaration we can use them in other places if we have access to this scope.

scopes can open up a lot of discussions here, and i don't think we need to dig down that rabbit whole. my example above should do the trick, if not determine in what scope/location you want your variable to be declared, and define there as in window.

Comment: What do you do if you want to assign the variable to the function scope?

Answer (score 0):

You have made good progress so far, but I think it will be easier while using an array.

This is pseudo-code but should give you an idea:

```
   var variables = [];
   var variable_name = (variable name after regexp you have done);

   variables[variable_name] = true/false; 
   // here the actual input acts as the key, much easier that creating a new variable with that name
```

Comment: If you're going to go that route use an object (key/value) instead of an array.